# Group by ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

I need to group the users based on created_at column by year and month,

`User.all.group_by{ |q| [q.created_at.year, q.created_at.month]}`,
 where I am getting hash with key [year, month], Is there any way to group the records which results like

```
{ 
  year1 =>{ month1 =>[array of records], month2=>[array]}, 
  year2 =>{ month1 =>[array of records], month2=>[array]}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 5: group records by "DateTime" field in tree view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349588/rails-5-group-records-by-datetime-field-in-tree-view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to the following:

```
User.all
  .group_by { |user| user.created_at.year }
  .transform_values { |users| users.group_by { |user| user.created_at.month } }
```

Comment: Is there any ways to get the count of the grouped records

Comment: the count of years? How about `:size` method?

Comment: count of the collection at month

Comment: How about this: `group_by { |user| user.created_at.year }.transform_values(&:size)` ?

Answer (score 1):

you can get by

```
result = {}
User.all.each do |user|
   result[user.created_at.year] = {} if !result[user.created_at.year].present?
   result[user.created_at.year][user.create_at.month] = []  if !result[user.created_at.year][user.create_at.month].present?
   result[user.created_at.year][user.create_at.month].push(user.attributes)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.  Although the suggested duplicate does propose a solution, there are other ways to achieve it.  One of them is using the code below (it's a refactor of one of the first answers).

```
{}.tap do |hash|
  User.all.find_each do |user|
    year = user.created_at.year
    month = user.created_at.month

    hash[year] ||= {}
    hash[year][month] ||= []
    hash[year][month] << user
  end
end
```

What's good about this code is that you are not loading all user records into memory (bad if you have, let's say, 1M user records) because it uses `find_each` which, by default, fetches users by 1000.

It also only goes through each item once, unlike the accepted answer in the duplicate suggested above.

Overall, there's a lot of ways to tackle your problem in ruby.  It's up to you to discover what you think is clean code.  But make sure that what you decide to use is efficient.